# Extract name of failure variable from cox model terms

Tags: r, cox-regression

I need to extract the name of the failure variable from a description of a Cox model in R. Note I don't have the object itself, I have `terms(coxfit)` that has been returned from a third party function. To give a reproducible example - suppose this is the model built within a third party program:

```
library(survival)

test1 <- list(time=c(4,3,1,1,2,2,3), 
              status=c(1,1,1,0,1,1,0), 
              x=c(0,2,1,1,1,0,0), 
              sex=c(0,0,0,0,1,1,1)) 

coxfit <- coxph(Surv(time, status) ~ x + strata(sex), test1)
# Third party program does a bunch of other stuff
# Returns as part of its output the terms for coxfit:
Terms <- terms(coxfit)
```

So after this I just have access to the terms:

```
> Terms
Surv(time, status) ~ x + strata(sex)
attr(,"variables")
list(Surv(time, status), x, strata(sex))
attr(,"factors")
                   x strata(sex)
Surv(time, status) 0           0
x                  1           0
strata(sex)        0           1
attr(,"term.labels")
[1] "x"           "strata(sex)"
attr(,"specials")
attr(,"specials")$strata
[1] 3

attr(,"specials")$cluster
NULL

attr(,"specials")$tt
NULL

attr(,"order")
[1] 1 1
attr(,"intercept")
[1] 1
attr(,"response")
[1] 1
attr(,".Environment")
<environment: R_GlobalEnv>
attr(,"predvars")
list(Surv(time, status), x, strata(sex))
attr(,"dataClasses")
Surv(time, status)                  x        strata(sex) 
       "nmatrix.2"          "numeric"           "factor"
```

What I want to do is extract the name of the failure variable - i.e. in this case the name is: `status`. Is there a simple function or some other way that will give me this name from the model terms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure how well this will work for what you specifically need to do. But it is a start

```
> library(stringi)
> 
> # Convert the formula to character
> terms2 <- as.character(Terms)
> 
> terms2
[1] "~"                  "Surv(time, status)" "x + strata(sex)"   
> 
> # Second element has the variable name of interest
> terms2[2]
[1] "Surv(time, status)"
> 
> # Extract the last word (also removes punctuation)
> stri_extract_last_words(terms2[2])
[1] "status"
```

So, in sum, you could do something like this

```
var_name <- stri_extract_last_words(as.character(Terms)[2])
```

Comment: Oh that looks handy. Will the failure variable always be in `terms2[2]` however if I specified delayed entry model for example ?

Comment: Great question but I am not sure. You could check and see is 1) it will be in the second element, and 2) if it will always be the last word. If it is different, post an edit and we can figure out a method that would extract the correct variable name in all cases. Also, if it is different, can you post a little more info about your overall goal?

Comment: It actually seems fairly robust. I tried things like include the parameter names: `coxfit <- coxph(Surv(time = time, event = status) ~ x + strata(sex), test1)` and it still seems to work. A delayed entry model worked too. Thanks for your help

Comment: Good stuff--happy to help!

Comment: So I've found out there is a base R command `all.vars()` that can be used to extract variable names from model objects, which I could use here potentially